# Using Arcane Abeyance to cast Fabricate, could you turn an enemy’s plate armor into a full body restraint?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature

If a player uses a bead with the spell [fabricate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fabricate) in it from the [Arcane Abeyance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#ChronurgyMagic) feature, could they turn an enemy in plate armor's armor into an iron maiden or just a full-body metal-binding?

Comment: It's unclear to me: What does the Chonurgy Wizard's *Arcane Abeyance* feature have to do with turning an enemy's suit of armor into an iron maiden?

Comment: @Rykara *Fabricate* has a long casting time but Arcane Abeyance allows it to be cast with an action.

Comment: @thom, I see. It's purely about being able to cast in combat. I was imagining a scenario where a guard was ambushed with the spell in this way (outside of combat).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### No. Plate Armor is not raw materials.

[*Fabricate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fabricate) states:

> You convert raw materials into products of the same material.

[According to wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_material), raw materials are:

> The term raw material denotes materials in *unprocessed or minimally processed states*; e.g., raw latex, crude oil, cotton, coal, raw biomass, iron ore, air, logs, water, or "any product of agriculture, forestry, fishing or *mineral in its natural form*.

Plate Armor is not raw materials - it is not unprocessed, minimally processed, or a mineral in its natural form, so cannot be affected by *fabricate*.

Comment: do you have any details for what qualifys as " raw materials"?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_material

Comment: The examples in the spell give good guidance. Trees, wool, flax, hemp, iron ore. It would need to be materials that have only been harvested and not refined / modified.

Comment: @thomas markov thanks! i was unsure if that was a game term, should i make a separate question for "If a player uses a bead with the spell fabricate in it from the Arcane Abeyance feature, could they turn any raw iron they have on them into restraints on another creature?"

Comment: @Aydens When you’re using arcane abeyance on spells that were never meant to be cast in combat, you’ve entered DM ruling territory. I can’t stop you from asking about every interaction you can think of, but I’d encourage you to consider if you really want to be told “it’s up to the DM” on a lot of these questions.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov that is fair enough